# Which MongoDB administration UIs offer a table view (OS X)?

Tags: mongodb

The only admin UI we found that offers a table view is MongoVue, which is only available on Windows. We're on Macs with OS X. Do any exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB has a good list of administration tools and interfaces [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/).  Of these, I've played with a couple mostly on Windows, but some options for you that should work on OS X (because they are Java based) are:

- [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/)
- [Umongo](http://edgytech.com/umongo/)

Of the two, I prefered Robomongo.  There is also an OS X specific tool called [MongoHub](https://github.com/fotonauts/MongoHub-Mac) that you may want to try out.

Comment: thanks, but as far as we know, none of these offer a table view like mongovue. is this not consistent with your experience?

Comment: I guess I wonder what you mean by "table view".  I am able to browse data in Robomongo by use of shell commands and data as a table doesn't really translate to MongoDB's document model.

Comment: look at the tableview screenshots here: http://www.mongovue.com/2010/12/06/viewing-hierarchical-data-in-table-view/. we prefer this model to the tree view, even for mongo data, because it more cleanly presents data for each document since attribute names don't repeat for each document.

Comment: @Crashalot: Robomongo includes a table view as well as JSON and text view.